# What's the `CPU Interface` of Switch?

Tags: cisco, switch, mac-address

What's the `CPU Interface` of Switch?

in the 2960-24TT Switch, there is a CPU Interface in it.

```
Switch#show interfaces | begin CPU
  Hardware is CPU Interface, address is 0002.1669.5897 (bia 0002.1669.5897)
  MTU 1500 bytes, BW 100000 Kbit, DLY 1000000 usec,
     reliability 255/255, txload 1/255, rxload 1/255
  Encapsulation ARPA, loopback not set
  ARP type: ARPA, ARP Timeout 04:00:00
  Last input 21:40:21, output never, output hang never
  Last clearing of "show interface" counters never
  Input queue: 0/75/0/0 (size/max/drops/flushes); Total output drops: 0
  Queueing strategy: fifo
  Output queue: 0/40 (size/max)
  5 minute input rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
  5 minute output rate 0 bits/sec, 0 packets/sec
     1682 packets input, 530955 bytes, 0 no buffer
     Received 0 broadcasts (0 IP multicast)
     0 runts, 0 giants, 0 throttles
     0 input errors, 0 CRC, 0 frame, 0 overrun, 0 ignored
     563859 packets output, 0 bytes, 0 underruns
     0 output errors, 23 interface resets
     0 output buffer failures, 0 output buffers swapped out
```

I have two questions:

1. What's the CPU Interface?
2. What's the `bia` meaning there?

Comment: Is this in packet tracer?

Comment: Each Ethernet interface on a Cisco router has its own Burned in address (BIA) MAC address. Burned-in-address on an interface never changes and you can compare it with what the manufacturer assign to a Network Interface Card on a host.

Comment: Did the answer help you? If so, you should accept it so that it doesn't keep popping up. Alternatively, you could provide an answer yourself and accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's exactly what it sounds like: the network interface connecting the CPU. It's rarely an actual phy-based NIC; most common is a PCI bus interface to the switch chip(s). It's how managed functions work -- management UI, spanning-tree, etherchannel, routing protocols, CDP/LLDP/etc, etc.